# How to repeat the last command on the command-line in the python debugger, PuDB

Tags: python, pudb

I'm on Linux and expected it to work like pdb, gdb, i.e., press `enter` to repeat the last command.  I understand the debugger has a `Variables` watch window.

Answer (score 23):

Ctrl-n/p - browse command line history